# How to scan SQL Server error log (and ignore some errors) with PowerShell?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I need a PowerShell script (2.0 compatible) to scan SQL Server 2008 R2 and later error logs. I need to have a list of phrases to search for, and a list of phrases to exclude.

```
param ([String]$instanceName=$(throw "Instance name was not supplied"))

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO')|Out-Null;
$sqlServer = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server") $instanceName;
$r = $sqlServer.ReadErrorLog();

$find = "Error:","Failed";
$exclude = "Error: 0x2098";

# need to do something with $r here and involve $find and $exclude
```

So, for example I want to find all lines in the ERRORLOG that contain `Error:` and `Failed`, but exclude the ones in the `$exclude` array. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a lot of info on this here:
[Use PowerShell to Parse SQL Server 2012 Error Logs](https://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/10/22/use-powershell-to-parse-sql-server-2012-error-logs.aspx?Redirected=true)

But one way to do what you are asking is by filtering the results when setting $r

```
$r = $sqlServer.ReadErrorLog()  | ? { $_.Text -match 'error' -OR $_.text -match 'Failed' -and $_text -notmatch "Error: 0x2098"}
```

You can iterate through each list and update $r accordingly, something like below should get you started.

```
Foreach($ExcludeText in $exclude){
    $r = $r | ? {$_.text -notmatch $ExcludeText}
}

Foreach($IncludeText in $find){
   $r = $r | ?{$_.text -match $IncludeText}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but the find and exclude arrays may grow, I'm wondering how to do it with the array, any ideas on that?

Comment: I added another example that I think hits closer to what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The above article has details on the undocumented TSQL version.

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/

I think you are missing some parameters.  The xp_readerrorlog extended procedure takes the following parameters.

A - Number of error log file

B - 1 = SQL Server log, 2 - SQL Agent log

C - Search string 1

D - Search string 2

Comment: Thanks but I'm not interested in a T-SQL Solution, and that script doesn't do what I want in T-SQL anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a powershell solution like you asked.

I think the order of the and/or is important??

```
$srv = new-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server("(local)")

$d = $srv.ReadErrorLog(0)
foreach ($r in $d.Rows)
{
   if ( ($r['Text'] -match 'Error:' -and $r['Text'] -notmatch 'Error: 0x2098') 
         -or $r['Text'] -match 'Failed:' )
   {

     Write-Host "============================================"
     Foreach ($c in $d.Columns)
     { Write-Host $c.ColumnName "=" $r[$c]}
   }
}
```

[image]